# strange 5-characters-sequence appear in PuTTY terminal with mouse click

Tags: terminal, putty, stty

While running some program (Configure), my terminal will be messed up. My typing is not shown. I can use "stty sane" to fix it but I notice that whenever I click my mouse on the terminal (I use PuTTY), strange characters appear. e.g.

```
# O:#O: O:#O: 7-#7- BE#BE ...
```

They seem to be 5 character sequences and if I click on the same location, the same sequence appears.

I know that I can fix it using "reset" but I want to understand what they are and if there is a way to fix it without reset. And maybe even a way to find the root cause of what inside "Configure" messed up my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are xterm-style ["mouse"](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Normal-tracking-mode) events.  You could in principle turn off those using a suitable `printf` or `echo`, but `reset` does it already as part of the `rs1` or `rs2` string in the terminal description (see output of "infocmp").

`reset` uses this for instance:

```
    rs1=\Ec,                                                                
    rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>,
```

and prefers the latter (the former is a hard-reset).  The `\E` is the escape character.  Offhand, that first chunk in `rs2`, [`\E\[!p`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-!-p.1C0E) is a soft-reset, which generally resets the mouse along with most other useful things.  A printf would be

```
printf '\033[!p'
```

which is more typing than

```
reset
```

(even if you use some non-standard `echo` which knows about `\E`).  But that comment about arrow keys: the soft reset puts the cursor-keys back in normal mode, while vi thinks they're in application mode.

To disable only the mouse, take a look at the output of `infocmp -x`:

```
XM=\E[?1006;1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
```

That tells ncurses how to enable/disable the mouse.  Your terminal description isn't exactly **that**, but the `1000` is the [normal mouse mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-l:Ps-=-1-0-0-0.1F7C) that your example shows.  So... you could do this

```
printf '\033[?1000l'
```

(lowercase L disables), and kill just the mouse.

You're seeing those because "some program" doesn't clean up after itself.

Comment: Thank you! That last printf 1000l seems to do the trick for my mouse!